# current route in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I trying to add routing to my angular1-page. I add next routes:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/mailbox/:id', {
            controller: 'BoxList'
        }).
        when('/mailbox/:id/folder/:folderId', {
            controller: 'BoxList'
        });
})
```

and after it, just after load page trying to get routes and current routes in console log (`console.log($route)`):

[image]

but if I try to get current route like that `console.log($route.current)` I've got undefined error, but if I try to get `$route.routes` it works well.

What's wrong?

Thanks!

UPD:

Controller look like this:

```
 MailboxUI.controller('BoxList', function ($scope, $http, $location, $route, $routeParams) {

    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    console.log($route);
    }
```

Comment: Can you create snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: show the controller

Comment: Snippet would be good, still not reproducible

Comment: You need to change route after reload at least, thus $routeChangeStart trigger and `current` available.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt, thanks! That's answer. It's just not loaded yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change route after reload at least, thus `$routeChangeStart` to be triggered and `current` becomes available.

But also [$routeChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#event-$routeChangeSuccess)

> Broadcasted after a route change has happened successfully. The
>   resolve dependencies are now available in the current.locals property.